# Why are the last characters in a cell in the input file treated differently in the output?

Tags: python, csv, newline

I'm trying to create a pronunciation dictionary with python which takes the words and splits them up into individual letters. The data are from a csv file with just one column and 37 rows.

This is the code I'm using

```
master = io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'ignore')

words = set()

for line in master:
    line = line.split(",")
    for word in line[0].split(' '):
        words.add(word)

def splitword(word):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(word)):
     
        output.append(word[i])
    
    return output

orthographic = {w: splitword(w) for w in words}

outfile = io.open('dictionary.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
for w in sorted(orthographic):
    outfile.write(w + ' ' + ' '.join(orthographic[w]) + '\n')
```

What I want is to generate an output file with the word and the word segmented into letters next to it on the same line. For example
*mast m a s t*
But it seems to treat words at the end of a cell differently and in the output the word is on one line and the split up letters on the line below it. This only seems to happen for words at the end of a cell. Any way I can make it so that the words are on one line and the separated letters on the same line, regardless of the position of the word in the cell in my csv file?

**Edit**
I tried to fix this with the `strip()` command but the output was exactly the same. This is the edited portion of my code:

```
for line in master:
    line = line.split(",")
    line.append([c.strip() for c in line])
    for word in line[0].split(' '):
        words.add(word)
```

Comment: Not looked at the whole question yet, but you can just do `list(word)` to split it into letters.

Comment: Looking a bit more, it seems that to answer this we are probably going to need to know how your `words` is generated - in particular how you read your CSV file - please can you show more of your code.

Comment: And can you please share a relevant portion of the CSV file you are reading?

Comment: Here's the first part:  master = io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8', errors = 'ignore')

words = set()

for line in master:
    line = line.split(",")
    for word in line[0].split(' '):
        words.add(word)

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add your formatted code there, instead of providing it in a comment? Thank you!

Comment: You need to call `.rstrip()` or similar method on the lines you read from the file, to get rid of the newline character at the end.